# How to get my focus back after wakeup

Tags: vb6

I am developing a desktop application with visual basic 6.0 which runs on windows suface(tablet) but the thing is it always looses focus when it wakes up after sleep

I've tried setting focus on event onResume of windows through winproc to last active form

```
lastActiveForm.SetFocus
```

but that did't work, I still need one touch to set focus and other to get going with normal event

I just want to cut down on First touch that is consumed for setting focus and directly goign with normal events when it wakes up from sleep..any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more details on what you stated here:

"I've tried setting focus on event onResume of windows through winproc to last active form"...

How exactly did you wire-up on event onResume?

In general, it's unusual to want to seize focus after sleep. Usually, the application that had focus is the one that will get focus when resuming from sleep.

If your app needs to always be on top, you could set a timer that checks to see whether it's on top every, say, second. If it's already on top, do nothing; if it's not on top, make it on top using the code in this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/186431

Unless your app is a whole-screen app that is designed to take over the computer, it is rather selfish to keep your app on top--you're not allowing the user to determine what is on top and what isn't, and that's just not Windows-friendly.

Comment: Application is full screen always on top approach will create some problems there, and for OnResume I used winproc and check the message for WM_SYSCOMMAND and SC_MONITORPOWER but thats not working for me

Comment: How do you expect the app to seize focus if "on top approach will create some problems"? When an app has focus it, by definition, is on top. Perhaps someone else can help you--I don't think you've clearly articulated the problem and your needs; SO will serve you best when you have a clear question with clear goals.

Comment: I need focus when It went to sleep while my app is running. The problem is it goes to sleep while my app is running and gets back not having focus back on my app...i don't know why

Comment: You wrote: "I need focus when it went to sleep". I think you meant: "My app HAS focus when the tablet goes to sleep..." When it awakes from sleep, what app is getting focus? What you're describing is an OS issue--not an application issue. Are you sure you don't have any on-sleep events that are programmed to fire upon sleep or any on-wake events programmed to fie upon wake?

Comment: I don't know what app is getting focus when it comes to wake is there any way to know in wondows xp or 7?